# ASP.Net RegEX for exact word search

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex

We have HTML String we need to search first occurrence and highlight that word in the HTML Text

Let us say we need to search "American Government" which can be in either of any format

Eg.

```html
American Government

<span>American</Span> <Span>Government</span>

<span>American Government</span>

<span>American </span> Government
```

We need REGEX which will search HTML to find out such combinations which will give us above all the Match in REGEX.

Without removing TAG still we able to search key word and add some additional Tag with this matches.

We need REGEX for how to get such kind of combination words from HTML.

Comment: (I'm editing and adding C#, but it could be VB.NET . I'm not sure... If you prefer re-edit it)

Comment: @xanatos: Why do you assume that it is .NET specific at all?

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). If the format of the HTML is variable (can be any valid HTML), RegEx is not a good solution.

Comment: @Tim Because the title is "ASP.NET RegEX". Now... Technically it could be Javascript, but (I hope) he wouldn't have specified ASP.NET Regex. Now. If Jigar tells me I was wrong (perhaps he is using an XSLT), I'll be the first to apologize.

Comment: @xanatos: Ah ok, i've read the whole question (before the edits) but left out the title. Therefore the `.NET`-Tag exists.

Comment: What is the definition of "text"? What if there were linebreaks (`<br />`)?

Comment: What if it was `A<span>merican Government</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a tricky one. I guess something like this?

```
(<[^>]*>)?(\s)?(American)(\s)?(\</[^>]*>)?(\s)?(<[^>]*>)?(\s)?(Government)(\s)?(</[^>]*>)?
```

Answer (score 4):

> We need REGEX which will search HTML

Oh no, believe me you [don't need that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You need an HTML parser such as [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: +1 for your answer, but the link to "don't need that" makes me want to donate all my rep to you. Sheer poetic beauty. We need more answers like that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to match. This regex will return *American* in the 2nd match group and *Government* in the 3rd match group.

```
(?ixs)(American)(?:(?!Government).)*(Government)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reformat your search term into a pattern.

```
string HighlightSearchTerm( string source, string term )
{
    Regex regex;
    string[] values;
    string pattern;
    values = term.Split( ' ' );
    if ( values.Length > 1 )
    {
        pattern = String.Format(
            "({0})|({1})",
            term,
            String.Join( @")(?=\s*<[^>]+>\s*)(.+?)(", values ) );
    }
    else
    {
        pattern = "(" + term + ")";
    }
    regex = new Regex( pattern );
    return regex.Replace( source, AddTags );
}
```

And then your MatchEvaluator will need to compensate for variable length groups.

```
string AddTags( Match match )
{
    string result;

    if ( match.Groups[1].Length > 0 )
    {
        return "<newtag>" + match.Groups[1] + "</newtag>";
    }
    result = "";
    for ( int index = 2; index < match.Groups.Count; index+=2 )
    {
        result += "<newtag>" + match.Groups[index] + "</newtag>" +
            match.Groups[index + 1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Input validation and optimization is left as an exercise for the reader. This also won't handle odd scenarios like `A<span>merican Government</span>`.